# Segmentation fault problem (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a struct named Game with an array of levels, defined like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
     Level levels[x];
} Game;
```

When I compile the code, if x is 1, 2 or 3, the program runs normally. If it's any other value (4, for instance), I get a segmentation fault. I'm not accessing the array anywhere. Main is something like this at the moment (commented everything except the initialization):

```
int main (...)
{
     Game g;

     return 0;
}
```

Any clue of what this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we please see what `level` is, or at least the size of it as far as static allocation goes? I have a hunch its huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How big is a `Level`? Is it possible you're overflowing your stack? Given that there's (apparently) only ever one Game object anyway, perhaps you'd be better off using the `static` storage class, as in: `static Game g;`

Edit: <strike>If you want to force allocation on the heap, I'd advise using `std::vector<Level> levels;` rather than using pointers directly.</strike> Oops -- missed it's being tagged C, not C++.

Comment: I'd agree that he's probably overflowing the stack, but the question isn't c++ :)

Comment: Or you can just move the declaration of g outside the main() function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just used static since I only have one object and it works that way. The program didn't cause a segmentation fault on my computer, but it caused on the one I was using at the time (it's really old so that was probably the problem). Level is a big class but I assumed it wouldn't cause a segmentation fault anyways.

Answer (score 5):

If the Level class/struct is really big, you could try using this:

```
typedef struct {
    Level *levels;
} Game;
```

and then allocating your levels with malloc() or new. Or if you really need an array of levels:

```
typedef struct {
    Level* levels[NUM_LEVELS];
} Game;
```

then allocating levels with something like this:

```
// Allocate levels
int i;
for(i=0;i<NUM_LEVELS;i++) {
    gameStruct.levels[i] = (Level*)malloc(sizeof(Level));
    initLevelNum(gameStruct.levels[i], i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On my machine, this code

```
typedef struct {
    char data[65536*4];
} Level;

typedef struct 
{
     Level levels[4];
} Game;

int main (...)
{
     Game g;

     return 0;
}
```

crashes, while it doesn't if I change the size of the `levels` array to `3`.

You should either reduce the size of your `Level` type (by putting data on the heap instead of the stack) or putting your levels on the heap (by keeping them in an array of **pointers** to dynamically allocated `Level` objects).

Comment: You could also make level global.  It probably isn't used in such a way that that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed have the size of your data and insist on having it stack allocated perhaps setting the stack size on the linker would be an option. If i am wrong please correct me as i find this topic interesting

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in similar cases you must declare the variable static:

```
int main(void) {
    static struct foo bar[SIZE];

    return 0;
}
```

Thus the variable will have been allocated and inserted into static area in compiled time.